# django/taggit - error: MyData objects need to have a primary key value before you can access their tags

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-taggit

I'm trying to use django-taggit ([see](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit)). This is what I have in my code:

models.py

```
class MyData(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=50)
    .....
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

views.py

```
g = MyData(title=f_title)   
g.tags.add( "mytag" )
g.save()
```

For some reason when I'm trying to save the tags and the data I'm getting this error:

> MyData objects need to have a primary
>   key value before you can access their
>   tags.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `MyData.objects.create(title=f_title)` for it to be saved to the DB and have an Id
then access `tags`

```
g = MyData.objects.create(title=f_title)  
g.tags.add( "mytag" )
g.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the order.  Save first -- which assigns  a primary key -- then mess with the tags.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, your MyData object must have a primary key before you add tags. This is because the tags are stored via a many to many relationship, and you need the ID so you can link it in a separate table. Simple solution is to do:

```
g = MyData(title=f_title)   
g.save()
g.tags.add( "mytag" )
g.save()
```